# how to add spf record without ip

Tags: spf

I am using a whm server which send default emails to me for any task(cron) executed but recently gmail started blocking my emails for not having spf record.
the dns of hostname i am using on server is managed by cloudflare, when i add spf record with ip of server (v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all) emails start working but i do not want to expose my ip address so how can i add spf record without server ip.

Comment: What do you mean that you do not want to expose your IP address? You're on the Internet, it is already public information.

Comment: by my ip address i mean my server's ip address and its behind cloudflare right now so nobody know's its ip address as of now. The reason i want to keep my server's ip address hidden is we have been ddosed before.

Comment: Then you can't really send email from it at all, because then its IP address will be known.

Comment: i am not worried about ip being exposed in emails as all emails are sent only to my gmail id but is there noway to add spf record by not adding ip address in it?

Comment: You could add an `a` or `mx` but those obviously get looked up to find the corresponding IP address, and must match.

Comment: is there any way i can change a whm server to send root emails using third party email service?

Comment: Probably. But you'll have to seek help elsewhere regarding that.

Comment: Just to be clear, the whole purpose of an dog record is to identify to the receiving server which **IP Addresses** are authorized to send email for your domain. So, no, you cannot have an spf record that does not identify the IP address of your server, if it will be sending email. Your IP is no secret. If you’re using cloudflare a properly configured firewall will prevent DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a crazy question, but direct email from your IP to Gmail will fail SPF check without a corresponding DNS record.  One approach is to use a middleman to complete mail delivery... without changing too much on your server you could use a postfix transport map to send outbound mail via AWS SES.  Then you can include amazonses.com in your SPF DNS record.